OtpNet Sha256 no valida el codigo TOTP
Estoy usando OtpNet... si uso Sha1 el código se valida correctamente, pero al cambiar a Sha256 ya no funciona la validación:
var totp = new Totp(secretBytes, mode: OtpHashMode.Sha256);

